# How to understand undefined variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

So, I want to understand how undefined variables works in JavaScript.

I have the following function to know if a word is palindrome.

```
function palindromes (word) {
    let reversedWord = "";

    for (let i = word.length; i >= 0; i--){
        reversedWord += word[i];
    }

    return word == reversedWord;
}
```

When I check in my console the `reversedWord` variable returns undefined instead of just the empty string `""`, and when I concatenated with the `word` string I get `"undefined" + "word[i]"`. Is this the expected behavior?. I don't understand why.

Comment: because arrays start at index 0, length is 1 greater that the last index. let i = word.length - 1;

Comment: How do you "*check in [the] console*"? You cannot access the variable from outside the function, it's declared as local.

Comment: @epascarello that was the problem, thank you. The first "undefined" was from the word array. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The first "undefined" was from the word array, my bad. Thanks to [espascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello) to point that out.